# What would be the best way to achieve this end goal in Wagtail?

Tags: django, model, content-management-system, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

What I want to create is a website where I can transcribe my current grimoire. I want my friends/others to be able to create accounts and 'bookmark' favorite pages to personal lists [I already know how to do this part]

The part I need direction on is that my grimoire is an ongoing project that I'm constantly adding new content to. It's organized into sections, and the sections have subsections, chapters, and subchapters. Entries can exist under any of these 4 areas. I want to be able to select where in the structure an entry goes when I am creating it. As for the frontend, I want to have a main 'Table of Contents' page that displays the hierarchy, with users being able to navigate to whatever information they want to see entries for, IE - if they click on "Section 3 - Correspondences", then I want to only show entries that fall under Section 3's subsections, chapters, and subchapters, and not show all content marked as a subchapter.

I've looked at everything I can find regarding book models, categories, tags, 'topic'-style mp_nodes, and I keep ending up confused. I don't expect to find something that directly matches my needs, but I'm not sure the best way to achieve this.

Should I have Sections, Subsections, Chapters, and Subchapters as snippets? Individual models? Structure blocks? Orderables? Am I over-complicating having a blog? If someone more knowledgeable could just give me a nudge in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.